# How to play guitar chord melody while keeping bass note on high fret?

Tags: guitar, technique, fingerstyle-guitar

To demonstrate:

```
E|-----------
B|--8---6----
G|--8----8---
D|-----7-----
A|-----------
E|--8--------
```

Which fretting hand fingering Should I use? Should I maintain bass note using thumb or 3rd (ring) finger? I need to keep bass ringing all the time.

```
    4   1
    4    4
       2
    3
E|-----------
B|--8---6----
G|--8----8---
D|-----7-----
A|-----------
E|--8--------
```

vs

```
    4   1
    3    3
       2
    t
E|-----------
B|--8---6----
G|--8----8---
D|-----7-----
A|-----------
E|--8--------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use your middle finger.

Some situations require you to use the thumb, but I don't think this is the case. If the position and dynamic doesn't strictly requires you to use your thumb, don't use it.

Also, be aware that the use of the thumb in that hand is discouraged in some styles, and not even possible in some scenarios.

I suggest you to check exercises and literature about fingerings for both hands before you continue practicing. You might be intensifying bad practices without knowing it. Be very careful with that since it will be much more difficult to correct those in the future.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Thumbs up! OP: Check some John Mayer live videos, he uses a lot of his thumbs!

Comment: @JCPedroza Thanks for your answer, can you add advice for fretting hand fingering? That actually was my original struggle with this phrase.

Comment: @Rumca Just use your middle finger. Using your thumb in the fretting hand is discouraged by many styles. Unless you are feeling very comfortable using your thumb, and there is absolutely no other way to play that, and you know what you are doing, you shouldn't be using your thumb on that hand at all.

Comment: Do not use your middle finger! The best fingering is as the OP shows, with the ring finger on the low C. JCPedroza, Using the middle finger means the 1st finger must switch from the Bb to the F# mid arpeggio limiting both speed and removing the option to have all notes ring out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the first answer got four up votes?? I assume the voters didn't attempt to play it.

Do not use your middle finger!

The best fingering is as the OP shows, with the ring finger on the low C. Using the middle finger means the 1st finger must switch from the Bb to the F# mid arpeggio, limiting both speed and removing the option to have all notes ring out. Using the thumb should be avoided unless no other options are available.

Comment: @JCPedroza suggestion seems fine. First finger can stay barre across frets so that it presses both A and F on top.